# How do you POST multipart formdata with an octet stream using aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am looking to send a request to an API that takes multipart formdata as an octet stream using aiohttp in Python. I took a look at the [docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/multipart.html#sending-multipart-requests) and was still confused about how to send a request properly. Further information about the API endpoint is [here](https://docs.ravy.org/share/5bc92059-64ef-4d6d-816e-144b78e97d89/doc/avatars-yZKcBrhlh1#h-check-if-avatar-is-fraudulent-upload-post).

If anyone could provide some examples or help me with this, that would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can't test it but it seems you have to create writer `with aiohttp.MultipartWriter('mixed') as mpwriter:` and send data directly as `bytes` - `mpwriter.append( b'hello' )` with prefix `b` - or `bytes` encoded from `text` - `mpwriter.append( 'hello'.encode('utf-8') )`, and later add to request `await session.post('http://example.com', data=mpwriter)`. and for `bytes` it should use `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure this out later when I have the time. That helps very much :)